# Cant update or add new post/page nothing is working in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, debugging, runtime-error

My site was working well last night but now nothing goes well. When I try to update existing page/post or add a new one it returns 505 internal server error and in Chrome it shows PHP code when I try to update any post.

What I tried:

1. Deactivate all plugins
2. Add php.ini with
   php_flag register_globals off
   register_globals = 0
   memory_limit = 64M
3. Tried to editing .hhaccess file but site stops working then i undo that
4. Tried 'WP_DEBUG' set to true for locating error but mozilla doesn't show anything and chrome shows the code.

Comment: See what happens if you make a php info page. check this in chrome and firefox. See if this work or you see the code in chrome. If you see still the code there is something wrong with your php installation

Comment: If you get a 5xx error, that's a server problem. Check your Apache/PHP logs.

Answer (score 0):

You need to contact your server admin to resolve the issue. This error generally comes up when plugin try to change the settings of your wordpress website